# How to read all email?

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch all email using the following code, but this code read all UNREAD messages however I want to read all Read/unread email.

```
 try {
        Properties props = (Properties)System.getProperties().clone();
        session = Session.getInstance(props);    
        store = session.getStore("pop3s");
        store.connect(host,username,password);
        folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");      
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Message[] message = folder.getMessages();     

        for (int i=0, n=message.length; i<n; i++)
        {
           System.out.println(i + ": " + message[i].getFrom()[0] 
             + "\t" + message[i].getSubject());
        }
}catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

can anyone please help me to read all email.

Thanks
Monali

Comment: check your pop3 settings. all emails will only come when enabled in pop3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard behavior with the POP3 protocol is that clients usually delete all messages that they've received from the server. Autodelete is not part of the protocol, it's more or less a convention or best practise that POP3 clients send *delete commands* after they received all emails.

According to this, a server does not have any *read* messages. All messages you can read are *unread*. And even if you leave messages on the server, you can't *flag* them as *read/unread* there.

That's different with IMAP protocol, where emails stay on the the server as long as you delete them, usually from your email client.